# calculatation day over day

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I need to calculate day over day

I attached the pbix file https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amd7BXzYs7AVhBBCo_Ls7q5IkrXH?e=d1nNmA

I've tried the following calculated measure but actually it returns wrong values, it returns sales for current date, but I need to return sales for previous day. How to correct it?

```
sales day over day = var _maxdate=CALCULATE(max('Date'[Date]), ALLSELECTED('Date'[Date]))
var _mindate=CALCULATE(min('Date'[Date]), ALLSELECTED('Date'[Date]))
var dates=filter(values('Date'[Date]), 'Date'[Date]<=_maxdate && 'Date'[Date]>=_mindate)
return if(ISEMPTY('Date'), BLANK()

, calculate(sum(Sales[Sales]), FILTER(Sales, Sales[Date]<=_maxdate && Sales[Date] >=_mindate && PREVIOUSDAY('Date'[Date])))+0
)
```

Comment: I can't download your PBIX. Do you have a relationship between `Sales[Date]` and `'Date'[Date]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your measure works. I've got sales for previous days.
[image]

You may need to use simple measures as follows:

```
TotalSales =
SUM ( Sales[Sales] )

PreviousDaySales =
CALCULATE ( [TotalSales], PREVIOUSDAY ( 'Date'[Date] ) )

DayOverDayChange =
DIVIDE ( [TotalSales], [PreviousDaySales], 0 )
```

The result (not on your data):
[image]